# django ModelMultipleChoiceField set initial values

Tags: django, django-forms, multiplechoicefield

I have the following code:

```
category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label="Category",
    queryset=Category.objects.order_by('name'),
    widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Product Category', 'class': 'form-control'}),
    required=True
)
```

how do I set an initial value in the select box like "Choose a category" so that the select box should have a list of categories with the initial value being "Choose a category"

Comment: You can use [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) attribute

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you pass a `QuerySet` object as an initial value and if `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`, then the check boxes are not checked.  I had to convert the `QuerySet` object to a list, and then the check boxes were checked:

```
YourForm(
    initial={
        "multi_field": [
            cat for cat in Category.objects.all().values_list("id", flat=True)
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: This is the answer that a lot of people will need. thanks!\

Comment: This worked for me, but could you please explain (or provide documentation reference) how this thing works? What is the loop performed here in `cat for cat in objects`

Answer (score 20):

You can pass it the "initial" setting from your view.  For example:

```
form = FormUsingCategory(initial={'category':querysetofinitialvalues})
```

The tricky part is that you must have the right queryset.  Just like the seed values, it must be of Category.objects.filter(...) - anything else won't work.

Comment: This is the only thing I could find online that actually works. +1

Comment: thankyou for the tip about getting the right queryset...  I had been trying to prepopulate modelmultiplechoicefield by overriding get_initial(), but the values never appeared because the supplied queryset was for the wrong model.

Comment: I cannot confirm this on Django 3.2.5, passing a queryset does not work, it has to be a list, as outlined in other answers

Answer (score 14):

Either set initial when you create form instance or set field initial in form **init**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["category"].initial = (
        Category.objects.all().values_list(
            'id', flat=True
        )
    )
```

If you just want to change the text when no field selected you can set empty_label property. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar in admin and in ModelForm i just did something like:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['category'] = list(Category.objects.filter(name=<whatever_you_need>))
```

and it worked fine for me