# Django too many values to unpack

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an error : too many values to unpack
It seems to be a problem with my list or may be it's an issue about the way I fill it.

views.py

```
        favs = FavoriteGames.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list('game_id', flat=True)
        mylist = []
        for fav in favs:
            game = Games.objects.get(id=fav)
            mylist.append((game.id, game.guid, game.title, game.logo, "checked"), )
            nogame = Games.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=favs)).values_list('id', 'guid', 'title', 'logo')
        form = GamesEditorForm(games=mylist)
```

forms.py

```
class GamesEditorForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.games = kwargs.pop('games')
        super(GamesEditorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['favorite_games'].choices = self.games  

favorite_games = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=True,
    initial=True,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    )
```

template

```
            {% for jeux in form.favorite_games %}
             <p>{{ jeux }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

in forms.py, mylist return :

```
[(1, 'paragon', 'Paragon', 'paragon.png', 'checked')]
```

This is my trackback :

```
Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.5.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'start',
 'myaccount']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/django-project/agora/myaccount/templates/base.html, error at line 16
   too many values to unpack (expected 2)   6 : <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   8 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myaccount/css/w3/w3.css" %}">
   9 : <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "myaccount/css/w3/w3-theme-blue-grey.css" %}">
   10 : <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>
   11 : <body class="w3-theme-l5">
   12 : 
   13 : <!-- Navbar small -->
   14 : <div class="w3-top">
   15 :  <div class="w3-bar w3-theme-d2 w3-left-align w3-large">
   16 :   <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-theme-d2" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images /avatar2.png" class="w3-circle" style ="height:25px;width:25px" alt="Avatar"><span class="w3-badge w3-right w3-small w3-green">0</span> {{ request.user.username }}</a>
   17 :   <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-theme-d4"><i class="fa w3-margin-right"></i>Agora</a>
   18 : <!-- Navbar big -->
   19 : 
   20 : <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small w3-right">
   21 :     <button class="w3-button w3-padding-large"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" class="w3-circle" style="height:25px;width:25px" alt="Avatar"><span class="w3-badge w3-right w3-small w3-green">0</span> {{ request.user.username }}</button>     
   22 :     <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-card-4 w3-bar-block" style="width:300px">
   23 :       <a href="{% url 'recap' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Mon compte</a>
   24 :       <a href="{% url 'logoff' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Déconnexion</a>
   25 :     </div>
   26 :   </div>


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/django-project/agora/myaccount/views.py" in view_favorite
  121.  return render(request, 'favorite.html', locals())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  173.             len_values = len(values)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __len__
  71.         return len(self.subwidgets)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  35.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in subwidgets
  57.             for widget in self.field.widget.subwidgets(self.html_name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in <genexpr>
  56.             BoundWidget(self.field.widget, widget, self.form.renderer)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in subwidgets
  559.         for option in self.options(name, value, attrs):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in options
  564.         for group in self.optgroups(name, value, attrs):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in optgroups
  573.         for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(chain(self.choices)):

Exception Type: ValueError at /myaccount/favorite/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: stacktrace please.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, sorry.

Comment: copy paste and post the complete error you are receiving in the question

Comment: I updated my post with the trackback, thanks for your help

Comment: It says you have an issue on 16'th line of your base.html `In template /home/django-project/agora/myaccount/templates/base.html, error at line 16`

Comment: Yeah, but it's not a big one. Django run well in genaral. It's only due to mylist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in `self.games` you have a list with items where each item contains 5 elements, eg. `(1, 'paragon', 'Paragon', 'paragon.png', 'checked')`

Each choice in [forms.MultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) is [forms.Choicefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField) which accepts a pair of values. The first one is for value itself (eg. 1 for pk) and the second one is for human-readable name (eg. Paragon for title).

In your case `choices` which are passed by `mylist` variable should be equal to something like: `[(1, 'Paragon'), (2, 'Paragon2'),]`

It also looks like you're trying to mark them as "checked". If you want to specify default values for them you can use `initial` field, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966527/django-modelmultiplechoicefield-set-initial-values) you can find some examples.